# SQL Server 2005 Pivot Table question

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I have an Entity-Value set of tables, and would like to pivot the results.
Here's the effect that I'm looking for, except you see that the SELECT stmt using Common Table Expressions isn't working exactly right yet.
My question is: Am I on the right track, or is there some sort of easy pivot command?

```
USE TempDB
Declare @Person TABLE(
PersonID Int Identity(101,1))
INSERT INTO @Person DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO @Person DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO @Person DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO @Person DEFAULT VALUES

DECLARE @Attribute TABLE(
AttributeID Int Identity(10,1) PRIMARY KEY,
AttributeName Varchar(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Attribute(AttributeName) VALUES('Firstname')
INSERT INTO @Attribute(AttributeName) VALUES('Lastname')

DECLARE @Pat TABLE( -- A Person's Attributes
PatID Int Identity,
PersonID Int,
AttributeID Int,
PatValue Varchar(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO @Pat(PersonID,AttributeID,PatValue) VALUES(101,10,'John')
INSERT INTO @Pat(PersonID,AttributeID,PatValue) VALUES(102,10,'Paul')
INSERT INTO @Pat(PersonID,AttributeID,PatValue) VALUES(103,10,'George')
INSERT INTO @Pat(PersonID,AttributeID,PatValue) VALUES(104,10,'Ringo')
INSERT INTO @Pat(PersonID,AttributeID,PatValue) VALUES(101,11,'Lennon')
INSERT INTO @Pat(PersonID,AttributeID,PatValue) VALUES(102,11,'McCartney')
INSERT INTO @Pat(PersonID,AttributeID,PatValue) VALUES(103,11,'Harrison')

SELECT Pat.PersonID,AttributeName,PatValue
FROM @Pat Pat
INNER JOIN @Person Person
ON Pat.PersonID = Person.PersonID
INNER JOIN @Attribute Attribute
ON Pat.AttributeID=Attribute.AttributeID
-- 

;WITH CTE1 AS(
    SELECT PersonID,PatValue AS FirstName
    FROM @Pat Pat
    INNER JOIN @Attribute Attribute
    ON Pat.AttributeID=Attribute.AttributeID
    WHERE AttributeName='FirstName'
)
,CTE2 AS(
    SELECT PersonID,PatValue AS LastName
    FROM @Pat Pat
    INNER JOIN @Attribute Attribute
    ON Pat.AttributeID=Attribute.AttributeID
    WHERE AttributeName='LastName'
)
SELECT Pat.PersonID,FirstName,LastName
FROM @Pat Pat
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE1
ON Pat.PersonID=CTE1.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE2
ON Pat.PersonID=CTE2.PersonID
ORDER BY PersonID
```

I just want a list of the 4 people, with their firstname and lastname.

Comment: +1 for actual test code to recreate issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good example [Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/)

Query in your case would look like this:

```
SELECT PersonId, FirstName, LastName
FROM 
(
    -- your query
    SELECT Pat.PersonID,AttributeName,PatValue
    FROM @Pat Pat
    INNER JOIN @Person Person
    ON Pat.PersonID = Person.PersonID
    INNER JOIN @Attribute Attribute
    ON Pat.AttributeID=Attribute.AttributeID
) up
PIVOT (MAX(PatValue) FOR AttributeName IN (FirstName, LastName)) AS pvt
```

Comment: In the pivot clause, you have to hard-code "FirstName" and "LastName"). This makes it hard if the attributes you want to retrieve and pivot can only be determined at run time.